# Button no longer works after implementing Google Analytics Event Tracking

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

Today I installed the google analytics event tracking code into my website to be able to track how many people are clicking the "Purchase ticket" button URL and thus see if our advertisements are effective or not as these pages can only be accessed through specific place this example is for facebook.

I had to Install the Updated Version of the GA Code, Google Tag Manager, and then insert onclick function into my  tag.

After successfully implementing it on this page: https://biscuitsandblues.com/popachubbyfb

I had tried to mirror what I had done on a few other pages to continue on, however I ran into a bug where after adding the onclick portion of my code to my next few pages the button was rendered useless and no longer took me to the URL. -> https://biscuitsandblues.com/curtissalgadofb   -or-   https://biscuitsandblues.com/earlthomasfb

The only difference between in code between the two pages is that the date has changed to reflect the current landing page.

Working button Onclick code:

```
<div class="ticketbutton">
<a href="https://www.opentable.com/r/biscuits-and-blues-reservations-
san-francisco?covers=2&datetime=2018-03-
02T18%3A30&restref=2474&searchdatetime=2018-03-02T18%3A30&partysize=2" 
class="myButton" 
onclick="trackOutboundLink('https://www.opentable.com/r/biscuits-and-
blues-reservations-san-francisco?covers=2&datetime=2018-03-
02T18%3A30&restref=2474&searchdatetime=2018-03-
02T18%3A30&partysize=2'); return false;"> Purchase Tickets</a>
</div>
```

Please help me figure out this madness! Thank you

Edit: Followed these instructions https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en

Comment: The purchase tickets buttons work (in Chrome and Firefox at least) for all three of the links you mentioned. And by work I mean they take me to the opentable site to buy tickets. Are you seeing something else?

Comment: Hey Steve, Thanks for the reply. I am looking at the lower button on the site not the top one which is a widget supplied by opentable. Yes you are correct that I want it to take you to opentable to purchase tickets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two separate methods:

1. using a gtag.js implementation: a streamlined version for tracking google analytics. see: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/
2. using a google analytics instruction for analytics.js implementation (without gtag.js). 
   See: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

In the standard google analytics implementation (analytics.js) an event is send to google analytics using the following format: 
`ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject])`, which is what you are using in your code.

The correct way to send an google analytics event with the gtag.js implementation is:

```
gtag('event', 'event_name', {
  // Event parameters
  'parameter_1': 'value_1',
  'parameter_2': 'value_2',
  // ...
});
```

The current mix up in implementation results in the following behavior: when a user clicks on the link the default link behavior is cancelled through `return false;` and replaced by the function `trackOutboundlink`. Because gtag.js is used and not analytics.js the `ga('send', ... 'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}});` part doesn't do anything. This results in the hitCallback not being called, and the link to stop working.

For correct tracking on your website change this:

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
```

to this:

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
  gtag('event', 'click', {
    'event_category': 'outbound',
    'event_label': url,
    'event_callback': function(){document.location = url;}
  });
}
```

Comment: And the winner is Aljosja! you are awesome appreciate you so much! Thanks for the insight ans solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go check your trackOutboundLink source on your page, but my only guess is that for cross browser safety, you should change `browser.location` to `window.location`

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){window.location = url;}
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, as per your suggestion I changed that piece of code to "window" and unfortunatley nothing has changed. still fully functional but not working none the less.

Comment: @AtlasKan Actually, it seems like you have a conflict with Google Tag Manager. It's not on this page https://biscuitsandblues.com/popachubbyfb and it works, but the google tag is on the other two pages.

Comment: Hrmm.. are you sure? Pulled the code straight from chrome https://imgur.com/a/1s00F.

Comment: @AtlasKan It looks I had an old cached version, because refreshing that first page, I now see the Google Tag Manager code and the button stopped working as well. In fact, I see that it's there twice https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-46725094-1 so that could be causing some issues.

Comment: So I removed the double lines of code (Tag Manager), I think there is something going on with the onclick function honestly. I added it to the "Artist Website" URL right next to the button and it completely stopped the URL from popping up as well. I don't know why I lost functionality but I feel like I am getting closer...

Comment: Ok as it seems I have located the problem but haven't fixed it. its the "Return False;" Snippet in the onclick link. If I take it away the button works but, I lose the tracking...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here @AtlasKan? I'm seeing similar issues.